# Large prime factors of n²+1

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Iwaniec proved (and many people extended) that the number of $n \le x$ for which $n^2+1=P_2$ (product of at most two primes) is $\gg x/\log x$. I am wondering what is known/can be proved for the counting function of a localised version of this problem $$\{n\le x \mathrel\vert\exists p,q\geq x^\alpha\text{ primes}:pq \mid n^2+1\}$$ for $\alpha> 1/2$ (or say $\alpha=1-\varepsilon$).

In particular, is it possible to prove a cheap *upper bound* of the (nearly) correct order of magnitude?

Comment: I found it hard to understand some of the quantification, so I edited, I hope in a way that clarified rather than obscuring or changing meaning.

Comment: Do you mean to count $n\leq x$ such that there exist two primes $p,q\geq x^\alpha$ with $pq\mid n^2+1$? Note that this condition does not imply that $n^2+1$ is $P_2$.

Comment: @GH: indeed, that is what I mean. You are of course right that this condition does not imply that $n^2+1\in P_2.$ The example is merely to illustrate that, some lower bound could possibly be given provided one can better localise primes in Iwaniec's proof, say.

Comment: This is related to the equidistribution of roots of $n^2+1$ modulo $pq$ as $p,q$ vary.  If one replaced $pq$ by a single prime $p$ then there is a famous paper of Duke, Friedlander and Iwaniec in this area https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1324141 .  Perhaps some of the methods in this paper or followup work can be adapted to your question, though I would imagine the specific question itself has not been explicitly addressed in the literature.

Comment: @Terry Tao: thanks! I was indeed aware of this result and the equidistribution mod pq should in principle be doable. Is there perhaps a cheap way to prove any decent upper bound for my question?

Comment: I think you get an upper bound of the right order of magnitude by first setting the variable $s = \frac{n^2+1}{pq}$, and summing over $s \leq x^{2 \epsilon}$ a bound for the number of $n\leq x$ where $\frac{n^2+1}{s}$ is an integer and the product of two large primes, and then bounding how often it is the product of two large primes the usual way using a sieve. Is that cheap enough?

Comment: @Will Sawin: would not this approach give a positive proportion of $n\le x$ as an upper bound?

Comment: @user334097 I thought sieves usually give an upper bound of the right order of magnitude (up to a constant factor) when optimized. I was thinking to use the methods of Brun's theorem, and in particular Brun's sieve.